# Hook de funções de classe (offset)

Tags: c++, classes

Eu não sei o modo certo para explicar esta questão, mas vou tentar do meu jeito.
Eu tenho um aplicativo .exe e eu preciso criar algumas personalizações para o executável, então eu criei uma DLL e dei hook para que as alterações sejam carregadas. Até então, todos sabem.

**O cenário é esse:**
Hook(0xOffset, &myClass::myFunc);

Há uma classe no .exe que eu preciso reescrever completamente e eu já fiz isso na minha dll, mas eu estou tendo problemas com o hook nas funções da classe, eles não são estáticos. Eu li muitos tópicos e eu não consegui implementar com os métodos que foram apresentados por outras pessoas. Em alguns casos, o compilador não aceitava, em outros aceitava, mas o .exe não encontrava o endereço real da função.

Poderiam me auxiliar? Algum exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu problema é conseguir o endereço de um método diretamente como `&myClass::myFunc`, bem, pelos padrão da linguagem isso não é possível, pois isso depende da implementação do compilador para as tabelas virtuais (VTABLE), um ponteiro para um método é um tipo especial de ponteiro, que pode conter o endereço da VTABLE junto de outras informações, então utilizar o operador & para conseguir o endereço do método pode retornar apenas a tabela e algum índice para ela e depois quando você for acessar com `myObj->*myFunc(...)`, o compilador saberá qual método chamar.

Porém alguns compiladores implementam uma forma de conseguir isso. Para o MSVC e GCC você pode conseguir o endereço real do método fazendo um cast assim, supondo que seu método recebesse um int como parâmetro:

```
size_t get_method_addr(void (myClass::*f)(int)) {
    return reinterpret_cast<size_t>((void* &) f);
}
```

A mágica está no tipo `(void* &)`. O problema disso é que para cada método que recebe parâmetros e retorne tipos diferentes será necessário reescrever uma função assim. Para nossa sorte utilizando C++11 com variadic templates podemos implementar uma função genérica que deduz todos os tipos e retorna o endereço:

```
template<class Class, class ReturnType, typename...Args>
size_t get_method_addr(ReturnType (Class::*f)(Args...)) {
    return reinterpret_cast<size_t>((void* &)f);
}
```

Agora você pode utilizar a função `get_method_addr` da seguinte forma:

```
Hook(0xOffset, get_method_addr(&myClass::myFunc));
```

Comment: Não sei nem como agradecer. Você salvou a minha vida! Estou a dias tentando fazer algo e não consigo. Muito obrigado!